# Iterate per row, Guava HashBasedTable

Tags: java, guava

How do I get all columns per row in a `HashBasedTable`?
I initialized it this way:

```
Table<String, String, Integer> table = HashBasedTable.create();
```

I want to sum all the values mapped to each row.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you call `table.row(r)`, you'll get a Map from columns to values that you can call entrySet(), or values(), on.

Comment: can i do the same with table.column(c) if i want to iterate over columns?

Comment: thank you. i thought that would be a problem since hashbasedtable is implemented this way: `Map<R, Map<C, V>>` accdg to the guava doc

Comment: Yes, that's true, but the implementation takes care of wrapping that to make it work.